# Javafx- how this multiple toggle buttons (in one group) actions are correctly configure for my need

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

This is what happens.
[But i need to return colors when i press other toggle buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxDGX.gif)

What I need to do is colors need to be back to blue after clicking on another button (while toggling another button need to untoggle toggled buttons)

Problem is when I toggle 1st button (working correctly - changing color on box). But when I press 2nd button while selected 1st button, 1st button color box color not returning to blue.

```java
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB1;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup G1;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB2;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB3;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB4;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C1;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C2;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C3;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C4;

    @FXML
    void TB1Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB1.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C1, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.RED);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C1, Color.RED, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void TB2Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB2.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C2, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.GREENYELLOW);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C2, Color.GREENYELLOW, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void TB3Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB3.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C3, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.GREENYELLOW);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C3, Color.GREENYELLOW, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void TB4Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB4.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C4, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.GREENYELLOW);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C4, Color.GREENYELLOW, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please.. (mind the __M__ 2 buttons are enough) and stick to java naming conventions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to set `onAction` property for the `ToggleButton`s. Just add a [ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to the `selectedToggle` property of the `ToggleGroup`. In that `ChangeListener` you need to do two things:

1. Change the color of the `Rectangle` associated with the newly selected `ToggleButton`.
2. Revert the color of the previously selected `ToggleButton`.

I reverse engineered a FXML file based on the code in your question. The below code is a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) with minimal changes to your code just to show how to use a `ChangeListener`.

File: fxmldocu.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Color?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<VBox fx:id="root"
      xmlns:fx="https://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1"
      fx:controller="FXMLDocumentController"
      spacing="10">
    <fx:define>
        <ToggleGroup fx:id="G1"/>
    </fx:define>
   <children>
      <HBox spacing="10">
         <children>
            <ToggleButton fx:id="TB1" text="ToggleButton" toggleGroup="$G1" selected="false">
            </ToggleButton>
            <Rectangle fx:id="C1" width="100" height="29">
               <fill><Color fx:constant="DODGERBLUE"/></fill>
            </Rectangle>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox spacing="10">
         <children>
            <ToggleButton fx:id="TB2" text="ToggleButton" toggleGroup="$G1" selected="false">
            </ToggleButton>
            <Rectangle fx:id="C2" width="100" height="29">
               <fill><Color fx:constant="DODGERBLUE"/></fill>
            </Rectangle>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox spacing="10">
         <children>
            <ToggleButton fx:id="TB3" text="ToggleButton" toggleGroup="$G1" selected="false">
            </ToggleButton>
            <Rectangle fx:id="C3" width="100" height="29">
               <fill><Color fx:constant="DODGERBLUE"/></fill>
            </Rectangle>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox spacing="10">
         <children>
            <ToggleButton fx:id="TB4" text="ToggleButton" toggleGroup="$G1" selected="false">
            </ToggleButton>
            <Rectangle fx:id="C4" width="100" height="29">
               <fill><Color fx:constant="DODGERBLUE"/></fill>
            </Rectangle>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Your `FXMLDocumentController` with added `ChangeListener`

```java
import javafx.animation.FillTransition;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Toggle;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FXMLDocumentController {
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB1;

    @FXML
    private ToggleGroup G1;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB2;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB3;

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton TB4;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C1;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C2;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C3;

    @FXML
    private Rectangle C4;

    @FXML
    void TB1Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB1.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C1, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.RED);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C1, Color.RED, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void TB2Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB2.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C2, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.GREENYELLOW);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C2, Color.GREENYELLOW, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void TB3Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB3.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C3, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.GREENYELLOW);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C3, Color.GREENYELLOW, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void TB4Action(ActionEvent event) {
        if (TB4.isSelected()){
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C4, Color.DODGERBLUE, Color.GREENYELLOW);
            ft.play();
        }
        else{
            FillTransition ft = new FillTransition(Duration.millis(250), C4, Color.GREENYELLOW, Color.DODGERBLUE);
            ft.play();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        G1.selectedToggleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Toggle>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Toggle> observable, Toggle oldValue, Toggle newValue) {
                if (oldValue == TB1) {
                    TB1Action(null);    
                }
                else if (oldValue == TB2) {
                    TB2Action(null);
                }
                else if (oldValue == TB3) {
                    TB3Action(null);
                }
                else if (oldValue == TB4) {
                    TB4Action(null);
                }
                if (newValue == TB1) {
                    TB1Action(null);    
                }
                else if (newValue == TB2) {
                    TB2Action(null);
                }
                else if (newValue == TB3) {
                    TB3Action(null);
                }
                else if (newValue == TB4) {
                    TB4Action(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that the "controller" class does not need to implement `Initializable` interface. It can simply declare a `initialize` method instead, as I have done in the above code.

Finally, an `Application` class for running the application.

```java
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Togglers extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Class<?> theClass = getClass();
        URL url = theClass.getResource("fxmldocu.fxml");
        VBox root = (VBox) FXMLLoader.load(url);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Also note that another possible alternative – which I did not explore – could be to [bind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm) the `selectedToggle` property of `ToggleGroup` with the `selected` property for each `ToggleButton`.

Lastly, (and before *kleopatra* adds a comment regarding it :-) consider using [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: naming conventions are _mandatory_ (__not__ optional) - please don't replicate violations of the question, and stick to the _M_ (or _S_) when providing a code example :)

Comment: @kleopatra a [convention](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/convention), by definition, cannot be mandatory.

Comment: oh yeah its working now. i see now how its work. thanks a lot.

Comment: yeah you realy reverse eng that fxml file. lol its cool man

Comment: don't see anything in the definition about mandatory or not. Anyway, you either want to communicate successfully or not. The quality of an answer that doesn't try its very best to communicate its content _to future readers_ suffers ..